# .NET Training courses help (Architecture / TDD)

Tags: .net, architecture, tdd

I am looking for one of 2 things, Test Driven Development, or Architecture Trainings on the West Coast.

If anyone knows a company that do those, I would really apreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jean Paul Boodhoo does a series of his Nothin' But .NET courses around the world, but has started remote courses at a discount this year.

http://www.jpboodhoo.com/training.oo

The course is not explicitly about architecture, but does cover some of that. There is a strong emphasis on driving functionality out through writing tests.

Comment: Interesting, I look further thanks.